# update table with other table value

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables department_referance and department which has code in department_referance is equal to department_string_id in department tables.

```
department_referance //table
id code   sl_flag
    DD01  1 

department //table
department_id department_string_id  sl_flag
               DD01
```

I want to fetch sl_flag value from department_referance and update the value in department table's sl_flag.

```
update sl_flag='(SELECT a.sl_flag FROM department_referance a inner JOIN department b on a.code=b.department_string_id)'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this query

```
UPDATE department d 
join department_referance 
dr on dr.code = d.department_string_id 
set d.sl_flag = dr.sl_flag
```

Answer (score 3):

You can update it by joining(`JOIN`) both the tables.

**Query**

```
update `department ` t1
join `department_referance ` t2
on t1.`code` = t2.`department_string_id`
set t1.`sl_flag` = t2.`sl_flag`;
```